# document.location.hash not updating URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the below script to toggle (show/hide) between different DIVs in the page (indicated below in the vas boxes =)

But this doesn't update the URL string when I'm switching between different DIVs. For example, if I go to example.com/#david-guetta it loads the div id=david-guetta onload, but when I click the link for div id=xx it switches DIVs visibility but doesn't upate the url string to be example.com/#xx

I've been playing around with this part below (document.location.hash.split('#').last()); and trying different combinations with document.url or document.href with no luck. Of course my knowledge of JS is super limited.

THANK YOU for your help!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7/prototype.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
</script>
<script id="domloaded" type="text/javascript">
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt){
    var boxes = $$('#all, #david-guetta, #xx, #zx, #djf').invoke('hide');
    var target = (document.location.hash.split('#').last());
    if(!!target && $(target)){
      $(target).show(){
          var string = document.url
      };
    }
    $('controls').on('click', 'a', function(evt, elm){
      evt.stop();
      var link = elm.href.split('#').last();
      if(link && $(link)){
        boxes.invoke('hide');
        $(link).show(); 
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you missed `.` or `#` on `controls`? Is the event firing?

Comment: Assuming the click event is firing, as @Tushar questions, I think the `evt.stop()` is preventing the anchor tag from updating the URL.

Comment: Thank you both. The event is firing without [.] or [#]... however per @SteveH. point once I removed the [evt.stop()] it worked! thank you so much, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If your JS knowledge is limited, maybe consider sticking to existing lib instead of writing your own one.

Try [jQuery-hashchange](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange), for example.

Here's an [example](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/#test1)

I assume this is exactly the behaviour you want

Comment: in terms of the string yeah that's the behavior I'm looking for, but again due to my limited knowledge of JS I wouldn't know how to use this in conjunction with the ability to toggle across divs